# How to share my question on twitter to get the Booster badge

Tags: support, questions, twitter, share-this

I have asked a question with 340 views.  Now I want to get `Booster` badge and I have an account on twitter.  I want to know how to share my question.

Comment: ok please ... . I think the question is useful and helps poeple thats the point or I think you should close all of the questions asked in meta because you will get them if you understand stackoverflow site.

Comment: Duplicate doesn't mean the question wasn't useful.  It means the answer can be found in the linked question.  There, I even upvoted you.

Comment: ok I got it but now this question has an answer I don't think now its good to close it I dont know if its correct tell me to delete it? or something

Comment: @imsiso Why? The answers will remain here. And if it's closed as a duplicate, there is a bonus link to extra information for other users visiting this question.

Comment: ok +1 to @bart so please sombody close this question.(-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To earn the Booster badge, it must be visited by 300 unique IP addresses *who came from the link you shared.*  It's a silver badge, it's certainly **not** going to be as easy as clicking a share button after it gets a few views on its own.

See [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Answer (score 5):

Click the "share" link on the post.  There is even an additional link on that popup to post it on twitter:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

To share your question on Twitter, click on the **share** button under your question and then click on the Twitter icon. From there, the rest should be clear.

Comment: ok I did that but no `booster` badget gaved to me and nothing added to my question showing me that it had successful done.

Comment: @imsiso It needs to get 300 views *from the share link*.  Sharing a link to a question that gets 300 views from people that didn't follow your share link won't give you the badge.

Comment: Good answer, but definitely needs freehand circles.